# What is import func, struct, class, and @_exported in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-package-manager

In Apple's github for the Swift Package manager they use

```
import func POSIX.isatty
import func libc.strerror_r
import var libc.EINVAL 
import var libc.ERANGE
import struct PackageModel.Manifest
```

[source](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Sources/POSIX/Error.swift#L37)

There is also a file where the only code in it is `@_exported` [source](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Sources/POSIX/fileno.swift)

```
@_exported import func libc.fileno
```

Is this a Swift 3 feature? I can not find anywhere that you can import a type in the Swift documentation and nothing on `@_exported`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can import only a specific part of a module, not a whole module:

> Providing more detail limits which symbols are imported—you can specify a specific submodule or a specific declaration within a module or submodule. When this detailed form is used, only the imported symbol (and not the module that declares it) is made available in the current scope.

From [Import Declaration](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/import-declaration)

For example `import func POSIX.isatty` will import function `isatty` from module `POSIX` instead of importing the whole module `POSIX` (which is BIG).

The `@_exported` attribute starts with an underscore. That means it's a private Swift attribute. Not a feature, an implementation detail.
In short, this attribute lets you export a symbol from another module as if it were from your module.

Comment: were these features added in Swift 3?

Comment: @lostAtSeaJoshua Nope. I believe that importing just a part of module was in Swift since the beginning. `@_exported` was originally `@exported` but still it was undocumented implementation detail.

Comment: What are the benefits of this? Faster compile times?

Comment: @Kdawgwilk No performance difference. We are talking about ways to resolve name conflicts between imported modules. There won't be any difference in compiled code.

Comment: isn't there a risk of rejection from Apple (when submitting to App Store) if one uses `@_exported` sine it is a private Swift attribute?

Comment: @Sajjon Nope, it's not private API, it's a language thing. It wouldn't be actually visible in the app bundle. However, don't use it. The thing won't exist in the language for long.

Comment: `The thing won't exist in the language for long.`. Actually, `@_exported` still exists, and I was recommended to use it [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-packages-sharing-code-between-libraries-while-exposing-some-apis-from-the-shared-code/49605/3) for my specific use case.